# Why does jQuery.data behave different from inside jQuery UI options-events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, properties, jquery-data

I am using jQuery v1.8.3 and jQuery UI v1.9.2. I have implemented the [Autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete) widget this way:

```
$('#input_id').autocomplete({
  create: function (event, ui) {
    // Initialize data
    $(this).data( 'custom', { property1: 'Hello', property2: { num: 1, funct: function() { ... return value } } );

    alert($(this).data('custom').property1) // Display 'Hello'
  },

  select: function(event, ui) {
    alert($(this).data('custom').property1) // Display 'Hello'
  },

  source: function(request, response) {
    alert($(this).data('custom').property1) // Display 'undefined'
    alert(this.data('custom').property1)    // I get 'TypeError: this.data is not a function'
  }
});
```

*Why* in the [`source`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) option I get `undefined` while in [`create`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-create) and [`select`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) events I get `Hello`? How should I properly access the `number` property in the `search` option context so to get `Hello`?

Comment: Where's the jQuery wrapper for "this"?

Comment: @kidwon - Sorry, what do you exactly mean with "jQuery wrapper"?

Comment: I suppose that at your last alert you are calling jQuery function on none jQuery object, aren't you?

Comment: (If I am understanding you then) I am not. The jQuery object is properly set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting undefined there, because apparently `this` inside `source` function refers to anonymous function, not to the INPUT you're assigning data to in `create` function.

Use other means to access input inside `source` function.

```
$('#input_id').autocomplete({
    create: function (event, ui) {
        // when using "this" here, you're refering to #input_id input
    },
    source: function(request, response) {
        // when using "this" here, you're refering to anonymous function
    }
});
```

To access your data within source function use following:

```
 // ...
 source: function(request, response) {
     // you don't need to wrap this.element in jQuery again since it is already wrapped
     this.element.data('custom').property1
 }
```

Demo for future quick reference: http://jsbin.com/ojesig/1/edit

Comment: How can I refer to `#input_id` inside `source` "block"?

Comment: @user12882 Use that: $(this.element).data('custom').property1

Comment: @roasted Thx for the tip - a quick note though - `this.element` is already wrapped in jQuery so no need to do it again to read its data.

Comment: I opened a [new related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749724/how-to-refactoring-a-self-declaration-depending-on-the-current-context) to make things better...